# What part of static initialization is thread safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety

If I have a global value getter like this

```
bool get_global_bool() {
    static const bool b{get_the_value()};
    return b;
}
```

I know that `b` will be initialized in a thread safe way but will I also be guaranteed that multiple threads calling into `get_global_bool` concurrently will never execute `get_the_value` more than once?

Comment: Yes, C++11 guarantees that the value is initialized once. It will block other threads hitting this initialization code simultaneously, then unblock after initialization is complete. At that point, the other threads have access to the already-initialized value, bypassing the entire initialization code which includes the function call.

Comment: I guess my question was more if it was possible the call to get_the_value happens before any synchronization happens and that the only thread safe bit is when the bool is "constructed" with the return value?

Comment: No, it's impossible, the entire expression is thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is according to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local
> variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar
> behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once).
>
> Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for
> already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean
> comparison.

Well, you can also validate it by checking the gen asm output, the output would be like following on x86-64 gcc trunk

```
get_the_value():
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR v[rip]
        ret
get_global_bool():
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR guard variable for get_global_bool()::b[rip]
        test    al, al
        je      .L14
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR get_global_bool()::b[rip]
        ret
.L14:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:guard variable for get_global_bool()::b
        call    __cxa_guard_acquire
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .L15
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR get_global_bool()::b[rip]
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L15:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR v[rip]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:guard variable for get_global_bool()::b
        mov     BYTE PTR get_global_bool()::b[rip], al
        call    __cxa_guard_release
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR get_global_bool()::b[rip]
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

and you can see the **get_the_value** is protected by cxa_guard and called only once

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they don't systematically use double-checked locking; it doesn't work on a lot of architectures. In this case, the compiler can see that it will work, because it has inlined the initialization function, and can see that it makes no changes to global state, but depending on the contents of the initialization function, with double checked locking, there can be exceptional cases where code in one thread will see the initialization as already having taken place, but will read other memory values where it hasn't taken place.

Comment: I'm talking here about the low level double checked locking shown in the disassembled code. It's possible to implement it using `atomic`, but to do this, the compiler will have to generate a fence or a membar or some such. Which isn't present in the assembly code above.