# Is it safe and can I get benefit from checking a bool variable before call_once

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it safe to check the `initialized` before std::call_once?
Does it reduce the synchronization overhead?
And here is my code:

```cpp
struct Data {
    std::vector<int> data;
    std::once_flag flag;
    bool initialized = false;
};

int run(Data& d, int l, int r) {
    if (!d.initialized) {
        std::call_once(d.flag, [&d]() {
            d.data.resize(5);
            std::generate(d.data.begin(), d.data.end(), [g = std::mt19937(std::random_device{}())]() mutable {
                return g() % 10;
            });
            d.initialized = true;
        });
    }

    // read only ops:
    assert(d.data.size() == 5);
    return std::accumulate(d.data.cbegin() + l, d.data.cbegin() + r, 0);
}

void func(Data& d, int l, int r) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        res += run(d, i, r);
    }
    std::cout << l << ',' << r << ':' << res << '\n';
}

int main() {
    Data data;
    std::thread t1(func, std::ref(data), 1, 2);
    std::thread t2(func, std::ref(data), 0, 3);
    std::thread t3(func, std::ref(data), 1, 4);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Comment: It's thread safe but in my opinion it doesn't have value, since call_once will most likely get inlined and essentially do the check for you, so why do it again?

statics use the same mechanism under the hood and are guaranteed to be thread-safe to be initialized only once.

Comment: @MosheRabaev No it's not thread safe, what gave you that idea? There's a data race on `initialized`.

Comment: You are not the first person who has tried to optimize a "once only" initialization routine, and what you're trying has been tried often enough in the past to earn a name for itself. Read up on the story of [_double-checked locking_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

Comment: P.S., You are operating under the assumption that whoever wrote the `std::call_once` you're using did not do as well as they could have done. In my experience, trying to improve on library code that ships with mainstream software development toolchains usually is wasted effort. In this age of open-source software,  if it isn't already about as good as it can possibly be, then it's likely that someone out there already is writing the fix that will be in the next release. (OTOH, If I am wrong, then you could file a bug report. Maybe even contribute your own fix. )

Comment: A bool is 1 byte, so there is no alignment issues, all writes are going to be indivisible and atomic, the other thread reading the variable will either read false and eventually it’ll read true, and so practically on all modern architectures this is a non issue. The assert may fire though but that’s nothing to do with a data race.

Comment: @MosheRabaev It is precisely how a data race in C++ is defined. And even limiting to currently realistic implementations, the compiler can reorder the write to `d.initialized` before `d.data.resize` and depending on vector internals `d.data.size()` may read `5` while `std::accumulate` would still operate on the previous vector allocation, causing a crash. All of this is completely unpredictable or highly implementation-dependent and why data races are always specified to have undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes good point it’s undefined behavior thanks

Answer (score 4):

One thread may be reading `d.initialized` in `if (!d.initialized)` while another is executing the call-once function writing to `d.initialized` in `d.initialized = true;`. That's a data race and therefore causes undefined behavior.

You can't add an external check to verify initialization. The whole point of `call_once` is to provide for that in a thread-safe manner. You would be copying its functionality if you correctly implemented such a check manually.

In your specific example it would be better to directly execute the call-once function in main before starting the threads. All threads will need to wait for the thread that actually executes the call-once function either way.

Comment: One thread may fail the assert if the vector initializing does not impact instruction reordering?

Comment: @mian I don't know what you mean. Without the `d.initialized` the assert is guaranteed to not fail. With `d.initialized` the program has undefined behavior and anything can happen.

Comment: I mean is it possible that one thread run `d.initialized = true;` before actual initializing the vector, and the other thread may read d.initialized is true but find out the size of vector is not right.

Comment: @mian The program has undefined behavior. It's possible for one thread to read `d.initialized` as `false` and then go on to execute the rest of the function *anyway*, skipping the `call_once`.

Comment: @mian Undefined behavior means that you have no guarantee on _any_ behavior. So the answer to any "is it possible" question will be "yes". It can also crash or just skip code altogether or anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is unsafe, but it's not standard. At least you should use mo_relaxed to guarantee atomicity.

Here is the assembly code generated by only using call_once+once_flag (in x86-64 gcc -O3 environment).

```
push    rbp
push    rbx
sub     rsp, 24
mov     rbp, QWORD PTR std::__once_callable@gottpoff[rip]
mov     rbx, QWORD PTR std::__once_call@gottpoff[rip]
lea     rax, [rsp+7]
mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rax
lea     rax, [rsp+8]
mov     QWORD PTR fs:[rbp+0], rax
mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:_ZL28__gthrw___pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE
mov     QWORD PTR fs:[rbx], OFFSET FLAT:_ZZNSt9once_flag18_Prepare_executionC4IZSt9call_onceIZ14simple_do_oncevEUlvE_JEEvRS_OT_DpOT0_EUlvE_EERS5_ENUlvE_4_FUNEv
test    rax, rax
je      .L13
mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:__once_proxy
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:flag1
call    __gthrw_pthread_once(int*, void (*)())
test    eax, eax
jne     .L10
mov     QWORD PTR fs:[rbp+0], 0
mov     QWORD PTR fs:[rbx], 0
add     rsp, 24
pop     rbx
pop     rbp
ret
```

Upon inspection, I notice the absence of optimization logic akin to test and return. This outcome is somewhat unexpected. Generating the code in other environments might yield different results. It's plausible that GCC didn't optimize this case due to its rarity. Addressing your second question, the added bool variable does indeed alleviate overhead in scenarios without contention

Alternatively, consider using static local objects to satisfy your requirements. As mentioned in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491835/what-part-of-static-initialization-is-thread-safe/77492709#77492709), static initialization with a function ensures thread-safety and initialization-safety, while maintaining high optimization. GCC employs a clever technique to implement static initialization. If you're interested, you can investigate the details further. I'll refrain from elaborating on this here.

Comment: Even if this wasn't still UB, I am pretty sure that any decent implementation of `std::call_once` will already do the fast atomic check before entering a slow path, see e.g. https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_once.c#L139 for glibc (which will be called into by e.g. libstdc++'s `std::call_once`). As you can see there, the check also needs to be at least an acquire and the store a release. Otherwise they won't establish any memory ordering on the evaluations in the call-once function. The compiler may reorder them freely.

Comment: In your shown assembly, the fast path logic is hidden behind `__gthrw_pthread_once`. It is linked to a different implementation at link-time depending on whether the application is going to be linked as single-threaded or multi-threaded.