# Are function calls that are used to initialize `thread_local` variables guaranteed to be thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, static, thread-safety

Consider the following implementation of `rand_double()`, in which there is a *`thread_local` function variable* `seed` that is initialized using `std::random_device{}()` in each thread:

```cpp
auto rand_double(double min, double max) {
    thread_local uint64_t seed = std::random_device{}();
    // ^^ Are the calls to std::random_device guaranteed to not interleave?

    /* Generate random `double` and return it... */
}
```

I have learned that the *initialization* of static function variables is guaranteed to be thread-safe. However, I haven't found a source that states if, when using a *function* to initialize the `static` function variable, calls to that function will not interleave. **Can someone confirm if using a function to initialize `static` (specifically `thread_local` - does it make a difference?) function variables is thread-safe?**

Comment: 1. Having several `std::random_device`s in a program is a bad idea. 2. A similar question was asked a couple of days ago. The entire initializing expression is thread-safe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What part of static initialization is thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491835/what-part-of-static-initialization-is-thread-safe)

Comment: A thread-local variable is a different object in each thread. There is only one thread that could possibly call the initializer of any given instance of the variable. So there is nothing that could interleave. If you are asking whether initialization of multiple _different_ instances of the thread-local variable may interleave, then yes, but that is not a problem. The different instances have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at what you're doing:

1. You create an `std::random_device` as an automatic (function-local) variable. This is thread-safe. That is a standard guarantee by the C++ standard, see section 16.5.5.10 Data race avoidance `[res.on.data.races]`:

> 2 A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly access objects (6.9.2) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s arguments, including `this`.
>
> 3 A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects (6.9.2) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s non-const arguments, including `this`.
>
> 4 [Note: This means, for example, that implementations can’t use a static object for internal purposes without synchronization because it could cause a data race even in programs that do not explicitly share objects between threads. — end note]

2. The current thread uses that random device to retrieve one seed value. That is thread-safe for the same reason. Yes, behind the scenes some synchronization will take place when the random devices access the shared entropy pool of the operating system but ensuring thread-safety in that is the library's / OS's job, not yours.
3. You initialize a thread-local object from that seed. Of course that's safe
4. You destroy the random device. Same as above

**Your use is thread-safe because each thread uses its own `std::random_device`.**

Now the question is, is this an advisable way of doing things? I see two issues with this:

1. It is rather expensive using one random device per thread. [Those things have some overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577246/why-is-random-device-creation-expensive/72577314#72577314)
2. It opens you up to [issues with the birthday problem](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/01/29/random-number-generator-seed-mistakes/). Two threads could end up with the same seed value. The chance is low (unless you create a huge number of threads) but present

Here is an alternative based on the suggestion in that linked blog post of using sequential seed values for threads.

```cpp
auto rand_double(double min, double max) {
    static std::atomic<std::uint64_t> process_seed = std::random_device{}();
    thread_local std::uint64_t seed =
          process_seed.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Or to save approximately two instructions and one jump per call by not checking the `process_seed` before the thread-local seed:

```cpp
auto next_seed()
{
    static std::atomic<std::uint64_t> process_seed = std::random_device{}();
    return process_seed.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
auto rand_double(double min, double max) {
    thread_local std::uint64_t seed = next_seed();
    
}
```

This should remove the birthday problem and will also reduce the cost per new thread. If you run multiprocessing (e.g. MPI) you should also factor the process index number into the seed.

One potential downside of this code is that using one thread's state you can guess the random state of a neighbouring thread. This might be an issue in certain server applications but for others such as Monte-Carlo computations this seems more appropriate.

Side-note: `std::random_device::result_type` is a simple `unsigned int`. You are zero-extending. If you want a true 64 bit seed, you need to make multiple calls. Something like this:

```cpp
std::uint64_t random_device_seed()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint64_t> distr; // full range
    std::random_device rng;
    return distr(rng);
}
```

And, yes, just to clarify: Something like `static auto seed = random_device_seed()` or `thread_local auto seed = random_device_seed()` would be thread-safe for the same reasons discussed above.